# SVG markup in PDF as generated from Jasper Reports

Tags: java, pdf, svg, jasper-reports

**Problem Statement**

I have a SVG markup sent from front end javascript to back-end action classes. I am using Jasper Reports to generate PDF which will contain the SVG image( i have markup data only). How do i do that.

**What i have tried**

I have tried to embed SVG image( having the link to image file) to the PDF file while generating reports.

**Looking for**

How to embed svg markup so that i can see the image in PDF. Any other best approach to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

In later versions of jasper reports you no longer need to add `class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable"` to the imageExpression.

It is the default in JasperReports 6+ and JasperSoftStudio (JSS) will remove it if you add it in the Source pane.

The Tomcat SVG file provided in the JasperSoft Community answer works nicely.  My own SVG file would show properly in MS Edge or Chrome but didn't appear in JSS.

When I added `width, height, viewbox` and `overflow` attributes to the svg element, it then did appear in JSS - so *try the example first* before trying the svg you actually want.

Comment: Please consider using the code notation for your code int he above answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to their own web site (here: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-add-svg-image-your-report-jrxml) you need to include the SVG using a special HTML element:

```
<imageExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable">
    <![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getInstance(new java.io.File("D:\\tomcat.svg"))]]>
</imageExpression>
```

Comment: Yeah, that again you are adding an SVG file directly right. So do i need to create a SVG image file from SVG markup received from front end and store in temporary location to refer it like suggested?

Comment: No, you just hand it a file of svg markup as the answer already indicates.

Answer (score 0):

As the question indicates the **absence** of a SVG markup **file**, you could stick to the answer by David van Driessche but use a different getter:

`BatikRenderer.getInstanceFromText($P{svgMarkup})` for example where `svgMarkup` is a parameter of `String` type containing the SVG markup data.

Comment: Must I escape all " in the parameter for svg code? It throws an error. Please share a sample of the parameter

Comment: @DavidDunham as `BatikRenderer` is `deprecated`, it is adviced to research a different approach. If you encounter exceptions, try to find answers within tha WAN or ask a question including your source code and full exception stack trace.

Comment: Im using jaspersoft 6.5.1, SVG's do not show up without BatikRenderer. What should I use? If I replace "jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer" with "jasperreports.renderers.ResourceRenderer" the graphic does not show

Comment: @DavidDunham best action would include posteng a brand new StackOverflow question including a [mcve] plus expectations and precise problem description with StackTraces as it is hard to get an idea on what you are doing from within this limited comment space right here.

Comment: Yes, however there is 0 output when using Batik / ResourceRenderer, there is no error in the console, so it does not even point me in the right direction... (the graphic just does not show up when using later)